# Generic object comparator field by field

Tags: java

Just for fun I wanted to try to implement a field by field, generic object comparator and this is what I did :

```
 private Boolean isEqualFiedByField(Object o1, Object o2){
   if (o1 == null || o2 == null || o1.getClass() != o2.getClass())
     return false;

   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   Boolean result = true;
   Map map1 = mapper.convertValue(o1, Map.class);
   Map map2 = mapper.convertValue(o2, Map.class);

   for (Object field : map1.keySet()) {
     String fieldName = field.toString();
     if (map1.get(fieldName) != null && map2.get(fieldName) != null)            
       result &= map1.get(fieldName).toString().equals(map2.get(fieldName).toString());
     else
       result &= (map2.get(fieldName) == map1.get(fieldName));
   }
   return result;
 }
```

Is there anyway to **improve** this code ? Make it cleaner, faster or treat edges cases I forgot ?

Comment: May be more suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Don't use `&=` and `result` variable at all, just return false if not equal and return true after the loop finished. I would also assert that `o1` and `o2` are of the same type.

Comment: I prefer `{ }` around the inner statements of `if` and `else` always.

Comment: The return type should be `boolean` (with a small b). In case you din’t want to follow @JaroslawPawlak, this goes for `result` too (no matter the name Boole is written with a capital B in English).

Comment: @OleV.V. Could you please explain why `boolean` return type is better that `Boolean` ?

Comment: A Boolean (capital B) is a reference to an object, so it may be FALSE, TRUE or null, and a caller would have to check all three possibilities. boolean (small b) is a primitive value and cannot be null, only true or false, so it’s simpler for the caller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current code uses ObjectMapper, you could also do this using reflection and not depend on any library. Not sure that's better, but something to consider.

I always put braces around blocks, even one-liners. You might later want to add a line to your `if` block and forget to add the braces.

You chose to handle the case with two null arguments by returning false. Is that a deliberate decision? You might want to put some JavaDoc on your method explaining this.

I think you could split your method into at least 3 parts, already indicated by empty lines in your current code. These parts do different things so could be handled in separate methods.

You are calling `map1.get(fieldName)` three times in your code (also `map2`). I would call it only once and assign the value to a local variable.

If you can get ObjectMapper (I don't know the class) to return a `Map<String, Object>` you can avoid all the `toString` calls later in the code.

Comment: It would be cool if you posted your updated code (just curious). Even though this is not really the format for StackOverflow :-D